# stop include from being placed at top of page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

just starting with php. including a list, using a shortcode. Issue is that the included list appears at the top of the wrapper in the DOM instead of where i'm placing it in the html editor:
the function (which i put in functions.php) is:

```
function objectlist() {
include("objects1.php");
}
add_shortcode('get_my_objects', 'objectlist');
```

html (wordpress html view):

```
<div class="listGenCont">
<div class="objectList1">
[get_my_objects]
</div></div>
```

but the output ends up being:

```
<ul class="thingsathome"> **this is the included list**
<div class="listGenCont">
<div class="actressList">**this is where i want it**</div>
</div>
```

wonder why this happens and how to fix it

Comment: try this plugin instead - http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/

Comment: @Vestimir Markov...i don't want to add plugins if not completely necessary, also i want to learn about this

Comment: Please, check this out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49675/include-php-file-in-content-using-shortcode and also this blog post: http://www.amberpanther.com/knowledge-base/using-the-wordpress-shortcode-api-to-include-an-external-file-in-the-post-content/

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan- reading it, great info

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan, in the example you reffered to, where does the file path get specified?

Comment: @user3108832 If you look the answer in the first link in detail, you can notice that there is an example use of the shortcode. It look like this: `[include filepath="/get-posts.php?format=grid&taxonomy=testing&term=stuff&posttype=work"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then check out this code snippet ([credits](http://www.amberpanther.com/knowledge-base/using-the-wordpress-shortcode-api-to-include-an-external-file-in-the-post-content/)):

```
function include_file($atts) {
    //check the input and override the default filepath NULL
    //if filepath was specified
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('filepath' => 'NULL'), $atts));

    //check if the filepath was specified and if the file exists
    if ($filepath!='NULL' && file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.$filepath)) {
        //turno on output buffering to capture script output
        ob_start();

        //include the specified file
        include(TEMPLATEPATH.$filepath);

        //assign the file output to $content variable and clean buffer
        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;
   }
}

//register the Shortcode handler
add_shortcode('include', 'include_file');
```

When you use plain include it gets evaluated at the start of the WordPress request. This example uses capturing of the output biffer to prevent this.

Comment: where do i specify the file path?